# How to get selected ID and parentid from Telerik RadDropDownTree

Tags: c#, telerik

I need to get all selected items from Telerik radDropDownTree and create xml document in c#

```
<telerik:RadDropDownTree ID="rddt" runat="server" CheckBoxes="TriState" DefaultMessage="Select documents" DataFieldID="ID" DataFieldParentID="parentID" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="ID" DataSourceID="ds2">
<ButtonSettings ShowCheckAll="true" ShowClear="true" />
<Localization CheckAll="Select All Resources" />                  
</telerik:RadDropDownTree>
```

How can I get ID and ParentID from selected items?

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
                           new XElement("Root",
                                  new XElement("Resource",
                                          rddt.SelectedValue.Select(x => new XElement("ID", x)),
                                          rddt.SelectedValue.Select(x=>new XElement("ParentID",x)))));
```

Many Thanks